# DataGridView is blank after Changing DataSource at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datasource

I have a form where when it was created it will this query

```
 public IQueryable<PatientInfo> showMyPatients() 
 {    
        DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath);
        var patientInfo = from patients in myDb.PatientInfos
                          where patients.Phy_ID == physcianID
                          select patients;

        return patientInfo;
  }
```

Once I call that I will insert it to a variable and pass it as a paramaters here

```
public void fillDataGrid(IQueryable<PatientInfo> patients) 
{                
       dgvMyPatients.DataSource = patients;
}
```

Sounds simple right? but when I run this query

```
private IQueryable<PatientInfo> searchPatient() 
{    
      DbClassesDataContext myDb = new DbClassesDataContext(dbPath);
      var search = from myPatients in myDb.PatientInfos
                   where (myPatients.Pat_ID == patient_ID && myPatients.Pat_First_Name.Contains(txtSearch.Text)) ||
                         (myPatients.Pat_ID == patient_ID && myPatients.Pat_Last_Name.Contains(txtSearch.Text)) ||
                        (myPatients.Pat_ID == patient_ID && myPatients.Pat_Middle_Name.Contains(txtSearch.Text))
                         select myPatients;

       return search;
 }
```

and pass it as a parameter to `fillDataGrid()` the DataGrid will have a blank value even though there is a result from that query

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = searchPatient();
dgvMyPatients.DataSource = bs;
```

**NOTE: Both of the queries return PATIENTINFO and I would be inserting in the same DataGrid**

Comment: I found out the answer for myself, is it legit to answer my own question?

Comment: Of course [answer-your-own-questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was, Replace my connection string , then changed in my query, there seems to be problem on my Query soo that is why  it is not working. it is not producing any result.

So what I did was, each time I call this event and change the datasource I use `dgvMyPatients.Columns.Clear(); and dgvMyPatients.Refresh();`

Answer (score 2):

Try to add these lines

```
dgvMyPatients.Columns.Clear();
dgvMyPatients.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvMyPatients.DataSource = bs;
```