# DataGridView is blank after setting Datasource

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have looked and found one question which was similar, though did not resolve my issue - that other question was [datagridview-is-blank-after-changing-datasource-at-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963416/datagridview-is-blank-after-changing-datasource-at-runtime)

I am sure this is a simple question with an even more simple answer..Working on my first Windows Forms application and finding some things a lot different from ASP.Net :)

So in this application I have the following:

- Main Form
- Toolbar on this form, opens up a second form to set application settings
- This second form has a tab control (2 tabs) with various textboxes/checkboxes/combolists/buttons

  - All of these work perfectly.
- On the second tab of this second form, along with more textboxes etc, I have added a DataGridView; called printerListGrid

In the code-view of this form I am trying to bind a List(Of Printer) to it

```
printerListGrid.DataSource = AppContext.printers.printerList
```

When I run my app and go to the form/tab the DataGridView is blank.

I have also tried:

```
    printerListGrid.Columns.Clear()
    printerListGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    printerListGrid.DataSource = AppContext.printers.printerList
```

Again - it's blank.

While debugging I can see that my printerList contains 2 `printer` objects. I can also see that these have been set to the printerListGrid by viewing the contents of the `.DataSource` property. Yet, the DataGridView is still blank.

I'm guessing there must be some way to re-render the grid?

For the sake of code-discolsure; this is what is in the `List(Of Printer)`

```
    Public Structure Printer
        Public id As Integer
        Public name As String
        Public material As Enums.Materials
        Public outputFolder As String
    End Structure
```

Let me know if there is any more code/description you need to provide help.

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention. I am trying to set the `DataSource` in a `Private Sub` which is called on the forms Load event `MyBase.Load`

**UPDATE #2**

I continue to play with this, trying to get it to work - I might be totally misunderstanding the control and its purpose.. anyway, I have also tried the following:

```
    printerListGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    Dim col As DataGridViewColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    col.DataPropertyName = "name"
    col.HeaderText = "Name"
    printerListGrid.Columns.Add(col)

    col = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    col.DataPropertyName = "material"
    col.HeaderText = "Material"
    printerListGrid.Columns.Add(col)

    col = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    col.DataPropertyName = "outputFolder"
    col.HeaderText = "Output Folder"
    printerListGrid.Columns.Add(col)

    printerListGrid.DataSource = AppContext.printers.printerList
```

This results in at least the grid showing rows; appears like 2. Yet they are not populated with the data from `List(Of Printer)`...

Comment: I usually do this with a bindingsource,  but for some reason it wont work today. Basically you set the list as data source in the bindingsource. Then you set the Datagridview Datasource to be the bindingsource. This way you can run Bindingsource.Resetbindings(true) which should update your datagridview. But I can't create a working example :/

Comment: Quite ironic eh :) and yep, I've tried that too. I'm also trying to bind the same List to a combo box. It binds, but the DataMember and ValueMember won't set. The list just shows 2 items reading AutoArtwork.Logic.Printer - I've tried setting these to all sorts. This is really irritating me today :)

Comment: Got thrown by the fact that I allways use properties. I'm not a big fan of global variables, and today my brain believed that Public and Property where the same thing.

Comment: I did too. in ASP.Net you can get away with Public; I've never ran into this problem so wasn't aware of the difference. Thanks again for spotting it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out what I did wrong. Basically try this:

```
Public Structure Printer
    Property id As Integer
    Property name As String
    Property material As Enums.Materials
    Property outputFolder As String
End Structure
```

Comment: If you caught it before edit I just wan't to say you can skip "Shared" that was there before.

Comment: Tried, didn't work for me. If it's any more help.. List(Of Printer) is being populated in the constructor of a Printers class with data from XML. All of this is populating and i can see it in the debugger - just can't get the darn thing to bind and display correctly.

Comment: that was spot on! So it needed to be explicitly set as a property then? again, thank you very much :) I can now pick my hair up and glue it back in :D

Comment: Yeah I added shared since I had declared Id as Integer = 0 etc. Then it needed to be Shared, which also made it not work :D Ahwell ripping your hair off comes with the job :P

Answer (score 2):

The fields that are being bound need to be properties, not public variables. For example, if you replace your structure with the following you will see the id's in the grid. You'd have to do the same property switch for your other variables as well to have them show up.

```
 Public Structure Printer
        Private _id As Integer
        Public Property id() As Integer
            Get
                Return _id
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _id = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public name As String
        Public material As Materials
        Public outputFolder As String

    End Structure
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is updated for VS 2022.  I too was having the same issues, but the documentation and the help on here has been a bit dated.  So, here is my simplified breakdown on how this works.

First, in the class definition, I put the DataTable and BindingSource as private entities:

```
Private dt_Famous As New DataTable("FamousNames")
Private bs_Famous As New BindingSource()
```

Next, in the class constructor (i.e., "Sub New"), after the InitializedComponent call, I define the DataTable, set the DataGridView up and link the DataSource to the BindingSource:

```
dt_Famous.Columns.AddRange({
    New DataColumn("FamousName", GetType(String)),
    New DataColumn("ImageCount", GetType(Integer)),
    New DataColumn("FamousLink", GetType(String))
})

grid_Names.AutoGenerateColumns = False

bs_Famous.DataSource = dt_Famous

grid_Names.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "FamousName"
grid_Names.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "ImageCount"
grid_Names.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "FamousLink"
```

If I didn't use the BindingSource and just set the DataSource to the DataTable, I would get the rows added, but they would be blank.  And I have the DataViewGrid all set up in the Designer.

I use a BackgroundWorker to fetch my data and store it in the DataSource (this is done in the ProgressChanged event):

```
dt_Famous.Rows.Add({sFamousName, 0, e.UserState(1)})
```

It really doesn't matter where you get the data, but you have to add it to the DataTable, especially if you are processing the data from an external source (like from a website, or flat file).

Once the backgroundWorker finished his (her?) task and on the RunWorkerCompleted, I set the DataSource of the DataGridView to the BindingSource and then reset the bindings to refresh:

```
grid_Names.DataSource = bs_Famous
bs_Famous.ResetBindings(True)
```

And that's it.  The DataViewGrid has all the data, even after I set most of the control up in Designer.  I hope this helps clarify anyone trying to do this in the future.  Some of the previous responses were dated and I'm trying to update most of the topics that I find useful.