# Updating the DataTable row from DataGridView after Filter has changed

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, datasource

I have a DataGridView control that I use a filter on.  That all works.  When I execute code through a background worker, I use data from that grid for the worker to act upon.  The worker then updates the grid (e.g. as in the number of records found in the process of him (her?) doing the work).

I got that working just fine, if I pass the index of the grid and depend on the grid remaining static.

Where things go sideways is if I change the filter.  Thus, the index of the grid changes, even the row that I was working with might not even exist in the filtered view.

So I start to search around for a solution, even found a few articles on here ([How Do I Get the Selected DataRow in a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895778/how-do-i-get-the-selected-datarow-in-a-datagridview)) that I thought might point me in the right direction.

When the worker reports his (her?) progress, the DataRowView is there for it to read, but it cannot update the ItemArray.

Here are some code snipets:

```
Private Sub bgw_PostProcess_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw_PostProcess.ProgressChanged

    Select Case e.ProgressPercentage
        Case 0
            '~~ This is the code that is failing.  The value of e.UserState(5) does not 
            '   get set to the Row.ItemArray.  (In debugging, it has a value of 9).
            '
            '   e.UserState(6) is the DataRowView that gets passed to the BackgroundWorker
            '   and in debugging is correctly passed and present.
            '
            e.UserState(6).Row.ItemArray(1) = e.UserState(5)

            ts_Status.Text = "Reading thread (page " & e.UserState(0) & " of " & e.UserState(2) & ")"

    End Select
End Sub
```

Even if this is not the right way of updating the DataViewGrid, I need a way to update the underlying DataTable that is bound to the DataGridView control.

Any ideas?

---

Added comments (per request).

If you are unfamiliar with background workers, allow me to explain.  The background worker is essentially a separate thread executed independently from the main executable.  It can call two sub linking it to the main executable: ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted.

When ProgressChanged is triggered, there are event arguments that can get passed from the worker to the main executable.  This is the "e" variable.  It contains an object passed back.  That code works well.  That is not the problem.  For relevant purposes here. e.UserState array is:

```
[5] the number I want to show back on the DataGridControl
[6] the DataViewGrid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem
```

The DataViewGridControl.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem gets set via a Queue object:

```
    qItemCount.Enqueue({grid_Names.Rows(idx).Cells("Name").Value,
               "https://www.mywebsite.com/" & grid_Names.Rows(idx).Cells("Link").Value,
               grid_Names.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem,
               0})
    bgw_PostProcess.RunWorkerAsync()
```

This code works and, as requested, I am posting it.

And the background worker makes the call to report the progress in the DoWork sub:

```
    worker.ReportProgress(iProcessType, {iPageCount, sName, iMaxPages, sThreadTitle, sThreadID, iThreadImageCount, drvGridRow})
```

drvGridRow is dequeued previously from qItemCount.  That all works just as it should.

However, placing a breakpoint of the

```
e.UserState(6).Row.ItemArray(1) = e.UserState(5)
```

and checking the variables in the Command Window, I get what I would expect.

```
>? e.UserState(6).Row.ItemArray
{Length=3}
    (0): "Person Name"
    (1): 0
    (2): "show.php?9524231"
>? e.UserState(5)
13
```

Notice ItemArray(1) is zero.  This is expected.

Now, when I step to the next line and recheck the variables, I get the same result even though an assigned value of 13 is made to ItemArray(1).  I even tried to hard code a value in there and it won't update.  There is no runtime error generated, VB just acts as if the assign worked.

According to Microsoft, this assignment should work.  See [DataRow.ItemArray Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.itemarray?view=net-7.0)

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code. We have no idea how `e.UserState` is set but it looks like you are trying to assign a `DataRowView` to a field in another `DataRow`, which makes little sense. Show us the relevant part(s) of the `DoWork` event handler at least. We may also need to see how you're call `RunWorkerAsyns` as well, if you're passing in an argument. Also, you say that things don't work but haven't explained what actually happens.

Comment: Also, can you specify how you're filtering the data? Are you actually getting all data first and filtering locally, or do you mean that you're performing different queries with different filters at different times? Finally, please explain what you're actually trying to achieve. If we know that then we may be able to explain how to do the whole thing step by step, rather than trying to address possibly multiple broken steps in what you're currently doing.

Comment: The data is read as per user request from a web page.  I fill a DataTable from the result of a web get response.  Then I set the DataTable to a BoundSource and once I have all the data I set the DataGridView's DataSource to the BoundSource.  That works perfectly.  For that code, I updated [stackoverflow article regarding grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179189/datagridview-is-blank-after-setting-datasource/76903265#76903265) for vb.net 2022.  Filtering is done by setting the filter on the BoundSource.Filter.

Comment: OT, the code you have posted would only compile with `Option Strict Off`. I cannot recommend strongly enough that you turn `Option Strict On` and respect the required data types explicitly. You can turn it `On` in the project properties and there will likely be multiple errors flagged where you are using late binding or implicit narrowing conversions, e.g. `e.UserState` is type `Object` and thus cannot be indexed, you you'd have to cast it as an array. You can also turn it `On` in the VS options so that it will be `On` by default in all future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed it the first time but the issue here is a misunderstanding of how the `ItemArray` property works. It is not "live" data. You use that property to get a full set of field values out of a `DataRow` or into a `DataRow`. Changing the array itself has no effect on the `DataRow` because it is independent of the `DataRow`. It's just an array, like any other, so setting an element just affects that array, not any object that the contents of the array may have come from originally. To do what you want using the `ItemArray` property, you would have to do this:

```vb
Dim fieldValues As Object() = e.UserState(6).Row.ItemArray

fieldValues(1) = e.UserState(5)
e.UserState(6).Row.ItemArray = fieldValues
```

You get an array of field values from the `ItemArray` property, you set the desired element(s) of that array, then you pass the array back into the property. Internally, the `DataRow` will populate its fields from the elements of that array.

The thing is though, there's no point doing that if you're only changing one field. If you want to change one field, just change that field:

```vb
e.UserState(6).Row(1) = e.UserState(5)
```

Now you're updating the actual field of the `DataRow` directly.

Comment: That did the trick.  Before I did the filtering I just passed the index of the row.  But seeing how the user can change the list while the background worker is running (and it could run for hours working), it limited me on what other tasks can be done.  By removing the ItemArray, the code works now as advertised.  Thanks!

Comment: And I should thank you again for the additional 35 errors when adding Option Strick On.  ;-)  I didn't realize that was even available (me = old dog learning new tricks) so now I will fix all of those late binding issues.

Comment: @GaryLSmith, if your issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. That way, everyone can see that you need no more help without opening the question.

Comment: It is basically.  However, by moving all the objects into classes after the Option Strick On, the program failed.  Because of the strict typing now, the background thread runs faster than what the ProgressChanged event can handle.  I fixed some (moving code out), but more work is required.  Don't get me wrong here, I prefer the Strick, it makes for easier code to read in the end.   Thanks again!

Comment: @GaryLSmith, I think that we've addressed the specific issue that you asked the question about. If you have another issue, by all means post another question, including the information specifically relevant to that issue.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll work on it tomorrow and if I get stuck, I will.  What I am doing is fairly complex so I may need to think about things.  Like I said before, I am a long way from my DOS programming days (and VB 4).